# How to write declared as function SplitEmailAddress($address)

Tags: php

Whose argument will contain string data consisting of a valid email address. this function will take the email addres as the argument and return an array with two keys: user to the username part and domain for the domain part of the address

Example:

```
$arr= SplitEmailAddress('myusername@website.xyz.com')

$arr['user'] should contain the string ----> myusername

$arg['domain'] should contain the string ----> website.example.com
```

Comment: you mean we should write SplitEmailAddress Function for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function SplitEmailAddress($email) { // valid email input assumed.
        $temp = explode('@',$email);
        return array("user" => $temp[0], "domain" => $temp[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```
function SplitEmailAddress($email){
    return explode("@", $email);
}
```

But since it's one line, no need for a function just.

```
$arg = explode('@', 'myusername@website.xyz.com');
```

Will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming email is always valid, the easiest would be:

```
function SplitEmailAddress($email)
{
    list($name, $domain) = explode('@', $email, 2);
    return array(
        'user' => $name,
        'domain' => $domain,
    );
}
```